# Getting this while generating .dmg using py2 app

Tags: python, py2app

I'm trying to generate .dmg file from .py file which is dependent on many modules, getting this error, can someone please help to resolve:

> Modules not found (conditional imports):
> * AppKit (pandas.io.clipboard)
> * CStringIO (qtpy.py3compat, spyder.py3compat, spyder_kernels.py3compat)
> * Carbon (astropy.utils.console)
> * ConfigParser (boto.compat, docutils.frontend, pip._vendor.distlib.compat, qtpy.py3compat, spyder.py3compat,
> spyder_kernels.py3compat, sqlalchemy.util.compat,
> yapf.yapflib.py3compat)
> * Cookie (pip._vendor.requests.compat, requests.compat)
> * DLFCN (torch)
> * Foundation (pandas.io.clipboard)
> * HTMLParser (nbconvert.filters.citation, pip._vendor.distlib.compat)
> * IPython.Shell ()
> * IPython.frontend.terminal (sympy.interactive.printing) [module alias]
> * IPython.frontend.terminal.interactiveshell () [module alias]
> * IPython.html.widgets (seaborn.widgets) [module alias]
> * IPython.iplib ()
> * IPython.kernel.zmq.iostream () [module alias]
> * IPython.kernel.zmq.kernelapp () [module alias]
> * IPython.zmq.iostream (astropy.utils.console)
> * IronPython (nose.suite)
> * Mykytea (transformers.tokenization_xlm)
> * Numeric (numpy.distutils.system_info)
> * Parser (Cython.Compiler.Main)
> * PyQt4 (IPython.external.qt_loaders, matplotlib.backends.qt_compat, matplotlib.tests.test_backend_qt,
> pandas.io.clipboard)
> * PyQt4.Qt (qtpy, qtpy.QtGui)
> * PyQt4.QtCore (qtpy.QtCore, qtpy.compat)
> * PyQt4.QtGui (pandas.io.clipboard, qtpy.QtCore, qtpy.QtGui, qtpy.QtWidgets)
> * PyQt5.uic.port_v2.as_string () [module alias]
> * PyQt5.uic.port_v2.ascii_upper () [module alias]
> * PyQt5.uic.port_v2.proxy_base () [module alias]
> * PyQt5.uic.port_v2.string_io (PyQt5.uic)
> * PySide (IPython.external.qt_loaders, matplotlib.backends.qt_compat, matplotlib.tests.test_backend_qt, qtpy)
> * PySide.QtCore (qtpy, qtpy.QtCore)
> * PySide.QtGui (qtpy.QtCore, qtpy.QtGui, qtpy.QtWidgets)
> * PySide2 (IPython.external.qt_loaders, PIL.ImageQt, matplotlib.backends.qt_compat, matplotlib.tests.test_backend_qt, qtpy)
> * PySide2.QtCore (PIL.ImageQt, qtpy, qtpy.QtCore)
> * PySide2.QtGui (qtpy.QtCore, qtpy.QtGui)
> * PySide2.QtWidgets (qtpy.QtWidgets)
> * Queue (gevent.queue, jedi._compatibility, joblib.externals.loky.backend.compat, partd.compatibility,
> pip._vendor.distlib.compat, pip._vendor.urllib3.util.queue,
> spyder.py3compat, spyder_kernels.py3compat, torch._six,
> urllib3.util.queue)
> * SimpleITK (imageio.plugins.simpleitk)
> * StringIO (argh.compat, babel._compat, boto.vendored.six, conda._vendor.auxlib._vendor.six, curl, docutils.writers.docutils_xml,
> mpmath.libmp.six, nltk.corpus.reader.timit, partd.compatibility,
> pip._vendor.distlib.compat, pip._vendor.requests.compat,
> pip._vendor.six, pip._vendor.urllib3.packages.six,
> pkg_resources._vendor.six, qtpy.py3compat, requests.compat,
> ruamel_yaml.compat, six, spyder.py3compat, spyder_kernels.py3compat,
> sqlalchemy.util.compat, srsly.cloudpickle.cloudpickle,
> sympy.core.compatibility, torch._six, torch.serialization,
> urllib3.packages.six, werkzeug._compat)
> * System (traitlets.traitlets)
> * Tkinter (imageio.plugins._tifffile, skimage.external.tifffile.tifffile)
> * UserDict (attr._compat, qtpy.py3compat, spyder.py3compat, spyder_kernels.py3compat)
> * **pypy** (gevent._tblib, msgpack.fallback, pip._vendor.msgpack.fallback)
> * **pypy**.builders (msgpack.fallback, pip._vendor.msgpack.fallback)
> * _cmsgpack (pip._vendor.msgpack)
> * _continuation (gevent.greenlet)
> * _manylinux (pip._vendor.packaging.tags, pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.tags)
> * _tifffile (skimage.external.tifffile.tifffile)
> * all (sympy.testing.runtests)
> * anydbm (future.moves.dbm)
> * apex (transformers.trainer)

Comment: no, didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the update, same, a little late to the party but changed the whole stack to Node & PKG https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg.